# tensorflow: Spatial Pyramid Pooling layer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Is there any implementation of [spatial pyramid pooling layer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4729v4.pdf) with tensorflow?

Comment: You might want to answer and accept this question yourself with the comment in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6011). :)

Comment: answer your own question according to your github issue and we can leave in peace

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, Spatial Pyramid Pooling is now available in [tensorflow addons](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/master/tensorflow_addons/layers/spatial_pyramid_pooling.py)